# Can't build mbedtls-2.28.6 for ARM M-7 (SMT32F767)

Tags: arm, mbedtls

I am slowly revealing magic of CMAKE, thus I am only capable to do basic operations...
I tried all what could I find on the StackOverflow and other sites,
but I never succeeded with building mbedTLS to be used for HTTPS MCU sever.

Whenever and whatever I try (CMake-build or mbedTLS/Visual Studio *.sln build), I end up with Windows SDK selected and never get a .lib I might use with microcontroler (STM32F67 ARM-M7).

Also I tried to use STM32CubeIDE and mbedtls/library + mbedtls/include files with several
#defines removed or added from mbedtls/include/config.h -> I am cycling in a loop with different build errors.

What Do I use?

**[gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10-win32.exe](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-rm)**

**[mbedtls-2.28.6.zip](https://github.com/Mbed-TLS/mbedtls/releases)**

**[cmake-3.28.1-windows-x86_64.msi](https://cmake.org/download/)**

Please, anyone gives me a detail list, how to get a mbedTLS.lib,
I could use for ARM-M7 STM32F767 ? (e.g. using CMAKE windows console)

Thank you